# Sorting a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have a cell array of numbers but the majority of the cell array is empty for example:

```
x = 

[]    [6]    []    [4]    []    []    []    [1]
```

I have a matching array y

```
y = [1, 3,1,5,7,3,1,5]
```

I want to get the index of the numbers from the cell array x and use them to get the corresponding values from y. So x(2) matches with y(2). I convert x to a array using

```
x = cell2mat(x);
```

But the problem is that it returns

```
x = [6,4,1]
```

This does not allow me to get the correct index so I can then sort X and then sort Y accordingly so the same indices match up. I tried to use sort that does not work for cell arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `y(x)`; that will return indices 6, 4, and 1 from the `y` vector.

Note that the order of the returned matrix will depend on the order of the indices in `x`; if you want to sort `x`, do it before running `y(x)`.